# How can I get usage from huggingface inference endpoints

Tags: huggingface

I have created a Hugging Face inference endpoint and I am trying to understand the pricing model. Currently, it is based on an hourly rate. Is there a way to determine the duration of the endpoint usage per request, as opposed to hourly usage?

Comment: Maybe reach out to the support, since you are a paying customer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I thought there can be a trick that I can use. I will try to reach out to the support.